# How to assign an external IP to the Istio Ingress Gateway with IstioOperator? [GKE]

Tags: istio

I want to assign an external IP to the Ingress Gateway of Istio.

I want to use the Istio Operator Spec.
So far I got this:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: demo
  components:
    ingressGateways:
    - name: istio-ingressgateway
      enabled: true
      loadBalancerIP: 1.2.3.4
  addonComponents:
    grafana:
      enabled: false
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
```

It's assigning an automatically IP to the Service:

```
kubectl get svc -n istio-system
```

Is not showing 1.2.3.4. for the EXTERNAL-IP

Is it only possible if I really own this IP over GCP?

Answer (score 4):

First you have to create an IP resource in GCP, and then you can give that IP here in the yaml below.

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - enabled: true
        k8s:
          overlays:
            - api_version: autoscaling/v1
              kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
              name: istio-ingressgateway
              patches:
                - path: spec.minReplicas
                  value: 3
                - path: spec.maxReplicas
                  value: 5
                - path: spec.metrics[0].resource.targetAverageUtilization
                  value: 60
          service:
            loadBalancerIP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
            loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
            ports:
              - name: status-port
                port: 15020
                targetPort: 15020
              - name: http2
                port: 80
                targetPort: 80
              - name: https
                port: 443
              - name: tcp
                port: 31400
                targetPort: 31400
              - name: tls
                port: 15443
                targetPort: 15443
        label:
          app: istio-ingressgateway
          istio: ingressgateway
        name: istio-ingressgateway
```

Comment: I had to comment out the overlays part to make it deploy the ingress gateway. Any explanation why?

Comment: what's your istio version  and what was the error did you get  with overlay ?

Comment: I use 1.6.2. and I just applied the OperatorSpec: k apply -f istio/operator/controlplane.yaml. There was no error message at all. It was just not rolled out. How can I log the errors?

Comment: you can try " istioctl manifest generate -f <istio-operator-yaml> " and dump the yml configuration, there you can check the deployemnt, svc  for this gateway,

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Just a note: I was able to accomplish the IP change with a subset of this configuration. I removed these sections:
- "overlays" inside k8s.
- "loadBalancerSourceRanges" inside service.
- "ports" inside service.
- "label" inside ingressGateways.